# Java - How to switch old way block of code null check to Optional null check?

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, refactoring, option-type

Trying to refactor my whole project.

l want this block to be simpler with Optional Java 8 null checks if possible to be the same results at the end? Thanks

```
List<EntityDto> ventolinLogs = new ArrayList<>();
 for (VentolinLog logs : ventolinLogsList) {
   for (String ventolinId : logs.getVentolinIds()) {

   Ventolin ventolin = persistence.get(Ventolin.class, ventolinId);
   String ventolinName= "";
   String ventolinFirstName= "";

   if (ventolin != null) {
     ventolinName= ventolin.getVentolinName();
     ventolinFirstName= ventolin.getFirstName();
   }

   VentolinProfile ventolinProfile = persistence.get(VentolinProfile.class, ventolinId);
   String ventolinProfileName= "";

   if (ventolinProfile != null) {
     ventolinProfileName= ventolinProfile.getName();
   }

   EntityDto LogDto = EntityDto.builder()
            .ventolinId(ventolinId)
            .ventolinName(ventolinName)
            .ventolinFirstName(ventolinFirstName)
            .ventolin

      ventolinLogs.add(LogDto);
   }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the code will get *simpler* by replacing those two simple `null` checks using `Optional`.

Comment: l tried, but l cant get results, confusing with Optional on object, and on my String objects, don't know how to connect everything to work with nullable and etc.

Comment: @akuzminykh , that is what l want as advice as well , thanks. Maybe l dont have to refactor all of this to Optional null checks.

Comment: You will not make the code simpler. I can see you can replace null checks with Optional.ifPresent, however, that will not change much. You could use an Optional.map method if you would like to return something from the object if your instance is not null

Comment: `Optional` was intended as returned value, and that is where it works best, in methods that may not have a meaningful result. In just this function alone using `Optional` for something directly doesn't help much, unless you change other methods to also work with optionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you can return an optional from the Persistence class or, like in the example, just create an optional, you can do the following:

```
ventolinProfileName = Optional.ofNullable(ventolinProfile).map(VentolinProfile::getName).orElse(ventolinProfileName); // or just "" in the last brackets
```

I would also extract the builder to a variable and pass it to a lambda:

```
EntityDtoBuilder builder = EntityDto.builder();
Optional.ofNullable(ventolin).ifPresent(vp-> builder.ventolinName(vp.getVentolinName())
.ventolinFirstName(vp.getFirstName()))
```

But you should take care of the default values, which are initialized as empty strings in your code

Answer (score 0):

Make persistence.get return an Optional. You can use `return Optional.ofNullable(result)` to do this in your `Persistence` Class.

In your code use can now use:

```
Optional<VentolinProfile> ventolinProfile = persistence.get(VentolinProfile.class, ventolinId);
String ventolinProfileName = ventolinProfile.map(VentolinProfile::getName).orElse("");
```

For more information check out some tutorials on optionals like here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional

But as you see, it won't shorten the code very much.